# angularjs - ui-router add module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `main.html` with multiple subpages:`users.html`,`usergroups.html`,... which all of them have their own app files and controllers separately: `mainapp.js`,`usersapp.js`,`usergroupsapp.js`,...

And I use `ui-router` to route to particular sub page as needed:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp",['ui.router']);
    myApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider
    .state('users', {
      url: "/users",
      templateUrl: "pages/users.html",
      controller : 'UsersCtrl'
    })
    .state('usergroups', {
      url: "/usergroups",
      templateUrl: "pages/usergroups.html",
      controller : 'UsergroupsCtrl'
    })

...
```

Everything works fine until I need to use one of the module `multiselect.js`in my `usergroups.html`. When I added it directly to `UsergroupsCtrl` in `usergroupsapp.js`:

```
var app= angular.module('myApp',['am.multiselect']);
...
```

But immediately I have an error:

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

Which `MainCtrl` is from `main app.js`. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: There can be version conflict-ion for multiselect.js and anular.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is correct way to add `am.multiselect` module dependency to your main `myApp` module:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['ui.router', 'am.multiselect']);
```

In `usergroupsapp.js` you should just have module *getter*, not setter (don't recreate module once again). Note, that there are no `[...]` when you retrieve existing module:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');
```